# x32dbg different assembly code when scrolling

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, disassembly

Normally when I scrolling the CPU window I am missing address `009ADBF4` and there are only `009ADBF3` and `009ADBF5`, and one `nop` instruction.

When I find references for the address `009ADBF4` and go for that address I see totally different instructions (the correct ones).

Then when I scroll up instructions changes back and address `009ADBF4` is missing again.

Does anybody know the reason of that? See pictures

Normal state:
[image: Normal state]

VS

Accessed by reference (correct assembly):
[image: Accessed by reference (correct assembly)]

Comment: x86 uses variable length instructions. The same bytes decode differently from a different starting point. Your disassembler is trying its best to make sense of the bytes but that might not work for example if there is embedded data or zero padding.

Comment: I looks like some of those bytes should not be interpreted as code. They might be data, or someone put them between code on purpose to fool the disassembler

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right it is an Anti-debugging trick in function which is responsible for software registration. Instruction on address 009ADBF4 should be 3A90 and it is not correctly interpreted as two instructions 003A and 90....... Is there any easy way how to fix it in x32dbg..... Something like instruction length correction?

Comment: Ok fixed, select instructions -> right click -> binary edit -> replace 00 3A with 90 3A. Btw all instructions above 009ADBF4 address till ret instruction can be noped... It is a non referenced junk...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because the application you trying to debug is checking for `IsDebuggerPresent` or that application is using algorithm changes that instructions to confuse you.
The solution is to bypass the anti-debugging technique.